# Is there any way to highlight the node on search in network chart when using highcharts in angular application

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to highlight the node on search in network chart when using highcharts in angular application

I have filtered the node from the group of nodes on search. Now i have the pillar data and node data. how can I highlight them.?

I don't find any documentation so for for this. also am new to high charts.

Any inputs or references are highly appreciated..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change state of the selected points to `select`:

```
selectedPoints.forEach(p => {
    p.fromNode.setState('select')
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ufmxpz6L/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

---

Or just change their appearance, for example:

```
selectedPoints.forEach(p => {
    p.fromNode.graphic.css({
        fill: 'red'
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0hL34rvx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css